# How do I substitute selected contents despite any regex characters in vim?

Tags: regex, vim

In following code:

```
int return_int_func() { return 0; }
float fv = return_int_func();
```

Obviously, compiler will warn me `fv` may lost precisions because of auto-casting. Face lots of those things, I want replace all stuffs with substitute command. In short, I want this:

```
float fv = static_cast<float>(return_int_func());
```

But real codes has lots of forms like that:

```
float fv = obj.int_field;
float fv = obj->load_int_field("name");
float fv = xx.yy->zz;
```

I want select my target (`obj.int_field`,`obj->load_int_field("name")` or `xx.yy->zz`) and replace it with `static_cast<float>(\1)`. I tried this:

```
:'<,'>s/\%V/static_cast<float>(&)/g
```

But vim replaces *all characters* in selected word with `static_cast...` and that isn't what I want at all. Then I tried this:

```
:'<,'>s/\(\%V\)/static_cast<float>(\1)/g
```

Vim also do the same thing. I have no idea how to replace *whole content* (and despite any regex characters) with my pattern. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is almost too easy! Here it is.

```
:s/\%V.*\%V./static_cast<float>(&)/
```

This is actually almost the same as the example from the `:help`. We can take away from this that we should all just have looked up [`:h /\%V`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%V) first thing in the morning ...

`\%V` is a zero-width atom that matches stuff that is selected in Visual mode. Here it can match at the start of the Visual area. `.*` then matches (greedily) as much as it can; its greediness is reined in by the final `\%V.`, which requires the last character of the match also to lie within the Visual area.

---

Tip: If you need to make this change many times over many lines, define the following mappings (even better: put them in your vimrc permanently).

```
nnoremap & :&&<CR>
xnoremap & :&&<CR>
```

Then you can repeat the substitution shown above by simply selecting something, and then pressing `&` to perform the substitution.

Comment: I finally got my leak.`\%V` represents a SINGLE character in my selection, right? So you use `\%V.*`. But I don't understand 2nd `\%V.`, I tried remove it and that command also worked.

Comment: No, `\%V` is zero-width, it doesn't actually match anything. It just makes an assertion about the *following* atom, namely that it must be inside the Visual selection. The `\%V.` at the end is required to prevent the match from running all the way to the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to paraphrase your question: You would like to Visual select some text, and then perform a substitution, where the selected text is also part of the *replacement* text.

I think in this case a macro is a much better tool.

To create the macro, first select the first piece of text that you want to wrap in the static cast. For example, select `return_int_func()`. (For each step, I'll show what the buffer looks like.)

1. When you're ready, press **`qq`** to start recording into register `q`, then press **`c`**.

   ```
   float fv = |;
   ```
2. Type the left part of your wrapper text, `static_cast<float>(`.

   ```
   float fv = static_cast<float>(|;
   ```
3. Press **`CTRL-R "`** (Control-R followed by `"`): this will reinsert the original text.

   ```
   float fv = static_cast<float>(return_int_func()|;
   ```
4. Type `)` to complete the change, and then Escape to leave insert mode.

   ```
   float fv = static_cast<float>(return_int_func()▉;
   ```
5. Finally, press **`q`** to stop recording.

At this point you have made the first change and also recorded it as a macro in register `q`.

For all remaining changes, simply select a target such as `obj->load_int_field("name")` and press **`@q`** to repeat the change.

Look up [`:help 10.1`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_10.html#10.1) for more information about macros.

Answer (score 0):

The `\%V` facility is really not for acting on the selected text as a whole; more for searching inside of that text.

Assuming that you are going to be putting this into a function or maybe mapping this to a key combination, here is an alternative approach that does what you are looking for:

```
:exec 'normal! gv"adistatic_cast<float>('|exec 'normal! "apa)'
```

Note that this will use your `a` buffer, so if you want to use another buffer you can change the two instances of `"a` with `"x`, where `x` is the buffer you wish to use.

Basically this is going to programmatically yank the selected text, insert `static_cast<float>(`, paste the text that was selected, and then insert `)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
:%s/float fv =(.*)$/float fv = static_cast<float>(\1)/g
```

Comment: Above codes just presented as samples. I want SELECT target by myself no matter it is included in what sentance. So it must be `:'<,'>s/xxx/static_cast<yyy>(zzz)/g` and I can input variant `yyy`,and `zzz` should be equaled with `xxx`.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you right, you want to do text substitution only on selected text. This is not so easy to do, at least no so easy as a `:s` command can do. Because, your visual selection can be in single line, can cross multi lines, also it could char-wise, line-wise, block-wise..

but it can be done with this function:

```
function! SubVisualText(pat, repl,flag)
    try
        let v_save = @v
        normal! gv"vy
        let s = @v
        let s = substitute(s, a:pat, a:repl,a:flag) 
        call setreg('v',s,visualmode())
        normal! gv"vp
    finally
        let @v = v_save
    endtry
endfunction
```

you use it by:

- source the function
- visual select the area (could be done by `v`, `V` or `Ctrl-V`)
- `:<ctrl-u>call SubVisualText(pattern, replacement, flag)<Enter>`

the `<ctrl-u>` is for removing the leading range, since the function doesn't need the range.

when you run it, it looks like:(I just tested with `Ctrl-V` selection)

[image]